# how to parallel hadoop job running in stand hadoop distritbuion 0.20.0

Tags: hadoop, scheduling, jobs

I have such a headache for a long time, current my hadoop cluster is like this, I have 40 salve nodes to run, each slave node I configure 25 mappers 10 reducers, so maixumally I can launch 40*25=1000 mappers and 400 reducers simultaneously. Ok, now I have following jobs：

job1: I configure to run 5 mappers and  5 reducers
job2: I configure to run 20 mappers and 10 reducers
job3: I configure to run 975 mappers and 385 reducers

Suppose I use default FIFO job sheduling, if I submit the 3 mappers consecutively, is it possible that the 3 jobs can run simultaneously?  so that the cluster is maximumly utilized?

Currently, I test it that at the mapper phase, it seems 1000 mappers can launched after submit the 3 jobs, however, at the reducer phase, it become very very slow, so that I wait a long time, none of the above job finish, it seems they are hang at the reducer phase.

I am not very understand the inherent reason for this, can anyone help me on this issue so that I can submit the job and sleep, then tomorrow morning I see all my jobs are finish by order? Do I need to use fair scheduling to make it work????

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to give solution - but I will try to give directions to find one.
1. If you have enough reduce slots in the cluster - probably your problem is not related to parallel job execution. At least I would not suspect it in the first place. 
2. I would suggest to use Fair Scheduler - it is specifically built for the parallel execution and resource sharing. 
3. I would suggest testing each job separately and only after each one running good - start parallel run. 
4. Slow reduce can have number of reasons but I would check the following (what I know): 
a) A lot of data passed (and thereof serialized) between mapper and reducer.  Take a look on File system bytes written counter to identify it. 
b) There is serious data skew and a lot of data come to the single reducer.